# iOS OpenGLES not rendering images on iPhone 5s+

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

I followed this tutorial for the first short bit on setting up a basic 2D game engine: [Basic 2D Game Engine Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9743/how-to-create-a-simple-2d-iphone-game-with-opengl-es-2-0-and-glkit-part-1) and completed the first bit to render a basic image to the screen. It works fine on the iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 simulator but not any simulator newer than that.

I decided to download his finished project to see if it works on the newer devices and it does. To try and figure out what was wrong I slowly deleted everything to the bare bones on his project and it still worked.

The next thing I did was delete everything in his project and ported over my code into his project directly. It still renders the image fine! So now I have two X-code projects running the exact same code (I could change code in one project and it affects the other one.) Despite this it still works in one project on the iPhone5s+ device simulator but not the other one.

They both work fine on the iPhone 4s simulator (I changed the background color just to prove they are both running on the same code.)

This seems almost silly to me, they are running the exact same code and all of the settings are identical. Does anyone have any idea what is going on that could make OpenGL-ES not work on specific device simulators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be some 64/32bit issue. Look for areas where you've cast pointers or where you used float instead of CGFloat.

Comment: I have a super small amount of code, I never used float. I only cast one pointer when setting the vertex attribute pointer:

glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, geometryVertex)));

Comment: Actually this is correct, I was using CGPoints. CGPoints are two CGFloat values which do not work properly on 64-bit devices. I switched my CGPoints to a GLPoint struct that I made which had GLFloats instead of CG Floats and it worked like a charm.

Comment: On 32bit, sizeof(CGFloat) == sizeof(float).  On 64, sizeof(CGFloat) == sizeof(double). That's what got me when I had this issue.